# i am working with servlets and i am stuck at one point where i want to update only those rows which are selected using checkbox

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, checkbox, sql-update

i am using JDBC servlets(Netbeans)and Mysql. I want to update only few selected rows whose check box is checked by user. The user will check the box if value is updated in that particular row. I am displaying the values from database table using text where it can be changed in text format and check the box once edited. I have project Code as primary key which is just displayed and cannot be changed once entered. 
Please help me with the same.
Thank you very much in advance for your help.
Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*; 
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class newna extends HttpServlet  
  {
    @Override
    public void service(HttpServletRequest request,
                     HttpServletResponse response)
         throws IOException, ServletException
         {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
         try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter())
           {
              out.print("<html>");
              out.print("<head><title>Servlet JDBC</title></head>");
              out.print("<body>");
              out.print("<h1>Servlet </h1>");
              out.print("</body></html>");

          // connecting to database
            Connection con = null;
            Statement stmt = null;
             ResultSet rs = null;
            try {
                 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con=DriverManager.getConnection
                     ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database", 
                  "root", "password");
         stmt = con.createStatement();
         rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT *FROM admin_pr");

     // displaying records

      out.print(" <form action=\"admin_pr_up\" method=\"post\">");
      out.print("<table border=1>");

      out.print("<tr>");
      out.print("<th>Project Code </th>");
      out.print("<th> Part Description </th>");
      out.print("<th> Project Start Date </th>");
      out.print("<th> Project End Date </th>");
      out.print("<th> Design Start Date</th>");
      out.print("<th> Design End Date </th>");
       out.print("<th> Edited </th>");
      out.print("</tr>");
      while(rs.next()){
          out.print("<tr>");
          out.print("<td>");
          out.print(rs.getObject(1).toString()); 
        //pr_code which is not   
        //changed and is primary key according to which i'll update.
          out.print("</td>");
          out.print("<td>");
          out.print(" <input type=\"text\"name=\"prdesc\"value=\""+rs.getObject(2).toString()+"\">");     
          out.print("</td>");
          out.print("<td>");
          out.print(" <input type=\"text\" name=\"pr_str_date\" value=\""+rs.getObject(3).toString()+"\">");
          out.print("</td>");
          out.print("<td>");
          out.print(" <input type=\"text\" name=\"pr_end_date\"value=\""+rs.getObject(4).toString()+"\">");
          out.print("</td>");
          out.print("<td>");
          out.print(" <input type=\"text\" name=\"des_str_date\" value=\""+rs.getObject(5).toString()+"\">");
          out.print("</td>");
          out.print("<td>");
          out.print(" <input type=\"text\" name=\"des_end_date\" value=\""+rs.getObject(6).toString()+"\">");
          out.print("</td>");
          out.print("<td>");
           out.print("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"edit\" value=\"edit\">");
          out.print("</td>");
          out.print("</tr>");
      }
      out.print("</table>");
     // out.print(" <input type=\"text\" name=\"pr_code\"\">");
      out.print("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"edit\"><br>");
      out.print("</form>"); 

  } catch (SQLException e) 
  {
      throw new ServletException("Servlet Could not display records.", e);
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
  {
      throw new ServletException("JDBC Driver not found.", e);
  } finally 
  {
      try {
          if(rs != null) 
          {
              rs.close();
              rs = null;
          }
          if(stmt != null) 
          {
              stmt.close();
              stmt = null;
          }
          if(con != null)
          {
              con.close();
              con = null;
          }
      } catch (SQLException e) {}
  }



    }
    }

    }
```

THE OTHER SERVLET CODE WHERE UPDATING TAKES PLACE

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;

 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

  import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.DriverManager;
  import java.sql.ResultSet;
       import java.sql.SQLException;
       import java.sql.Statement;
      import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;



public class admin_pr_up extends HttpServlet {


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException{

    Connection connection = null;
    Statement istmt = null;
     ResultSet rs = null;
       //ResultSet rs1 = null;


    try{

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database", "root", "password");
        istmt = connection.createStatement();

        rs=istmt.executeQuery("select * from admin_pr ");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

              String[] cbox = request.getParameterValues("cbox");

                     for(int i=1;i<=cbox.length;i++)
                  {  
                      if (cbox!= null)
                      {  

                       out.print("CHECKED");
                      } 


                  }   



    }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
    }finally{



        try{        

            istmt.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
        }  


    }
 }
```

}

Comment: What's the problem, exactly?

Comment: @Slava Imeshev my problem is im not able to know which row's checkbox is checked so that i can edit that particular row in the table as shown in second program i get checked output  for number of rows selected but i don't get to know which row is checked..i want to know which row is checked??

Comment: can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

That's easy. The browser will send the checked box as a parameter on submit only if the check box is checked checked.  Your case is more complicated because you have a table, so you will need to distiguish between check boxes in a row by giving check boxes a value that is unique to the table row

```
 out.print("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"edit\" value=\"edit\"" + someId + ">");
```

where someId is an ID unique for the record, you'll figure out what it should be  yourself as you know the structure of the table. A value of a primary key column usually works great.

The part of the code the processes a request will receive a multi-value parameter "edit" that would contain values of all checked boxes. Pseudo-code:

```
edit: edit1, edit5, edit6
```

All you'll have to do is to handle the sections.

Good luck!